# NameError: name 'self' is not defined: Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have two programs in python. The Program contains a class and function init and second program is for calling the program1.

I am getting below error which is mentioned in the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igjWV.png)

Here are the two programs:
f1.py

---

```
class Getdata:
def __init__(self):
    self.IMAGE_SIZE = 112
    self.IMAGES_LENGTH = 150
    self.call_data()
def call_data(self):
    x = 10
    y = self.IMAGES_LENGTH
    z = self.IMAGE_SIZE
    return x,y,z
```

mainclass.py

---

```
from f1 import Getdata
x_train, y_train, z_train = Getdata.call_data(self)
print(x_train, y_train, z_train)
```

Comment: Where do you think `self` would be defined??? You seem to fundamentally not understand the purpose of a class... so why use a class at all?

Comment: Yeah, that `Getdata` thing doesn't make any sense as a class.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You firstly need to instantiate the class, and you do not have to pass the `self` parameter when calling a class function, modify f1.py to look like this:

```
from f1 import Getdata
getdata = Getdata()
x_train, y_train, z_train = getdata.call_data()
print(x_train, y_train, z_train)
```